# Rsyslog Central Server Log Rotation File/Folder Permission

Tags: linux, centos, logging, rsyslog, rotation

I have setup a CentOS 6.3 box to collect logs from a few devices, I have log rotation setup for each host. Basically It rotates the log file by Year, Month, Day and the Host.

Everything works great except it seems the Rsyslog daemon creates the files/folders with root:root owner & group. I then can't navigate into the day folder e.g 06, 07, 08 without changing the permissions first.

I can navigate with root of course but this isn't ideal.

Is there a way to get the Rsyslog Daemon to create the folders with a specific group (sysadmin) that my user is apart of.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the configuration directives [`$DirGroup`, `$DirUser`, `$FileGroup` and `$FileUser`](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/omfile.html) to set the user and group ID you want for newly created directories and files, respectively.